# Extending Parcelable to read another Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class that extends Parcelable, we'll call it Class A.

I have another class that extends Parcelable, we'll call it Class B.

One of the member variables of A is an ArrayList of Class B objects.

I'm trying to write the Parcelable overrides, but can't figure out how to save and read the ArrayList of Class B.

There are methods to read and write ArrayLists, but they want a parameter which is a ClassLoader and I am unfamiliar with it.  I could also copy the ArrayList into an array and user the methods to read and write a Parcelable array, but this also requires a ClassLoader parameter.

Update:

It looks like

```
in.readTypedList(mList, ClassB.CREATOR);
```

and

```
out.writeTypedList(mList);
```

are what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `null` as `ClassLoader` to use the default one.

`Parcel.readTypedList()` and `Parcel.writeTypedList()` seem to be OK. Or you can use `Parcel.readParcelableArray()` and `Parcel.writeParcelableArray()` and convert the list to array.

Comment: OK... but what to do to read from a Parcel into a final list? I get "may not have been initialized". Will readTypedList use an existing one, or insist on creating it anew?

Comment: If the list is final it doesn't mean it's constant so you can just pass the list to the `readTypedList()` method and it will be populated with previously written objects. But before calling the method you need to initialize the list, for instance, `final List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();`.

Comment: `readTypedList()` doesn't create a `List` for you. You should do it yourself before calling the method.